# Pandas-Python how to extract data from a column

Tags: python, pandas

Panda receive data from a url and make a data table, how do I extract a specific column from this dataframe into a list. Specifically, here is my code to allow panda to retrieve the information from the url

```
url="https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/nasdaq-listings/nasdaq-listed_csv/data/7665719fb51081ba0bd834fde71ce822/nasdaq-listed_csv.csv"
req = requests.get(url).content
companies = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(req.decode('utf-8')))
```

and when I do
`print(companies)`
I get the following result:

[image]

My desire output is to be able to extract the data from the Symbol column into a list so the list will contain `['Symbol', 'AAIT', 'AAL', ...'ZUMZ']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your use case:

```py
# You can create the Symbols list with this:
symbols_list = companies['Symbol'].to_list()

# This is not really needed. But as you want to have "Symbol" word at the start, you can do the following
your_desired_list = ['Symbol']
your_desired_list += symbols_list
```